# Example of tensor algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am trying to make sense of the tensor algebra product, as given as an example in Dummit and Foote. Let $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and let $M=\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ and consider $M$ as an $R$-module. Since $M\otimes_R M=0$, we have that $\mathcal{T}(M)=\mathbb{Z}\oplus(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$.

The authors claim that the multiplication is given by $(r,\overline{p})(s,\overline{q})=(rs,\overline{rq+sp})$, but I do not see why this is true. If we consider these elements as sums, by distributing we should have $(r+\overline{p})(s+\overline{q})=rs+r\overline{q}+\overline{p}s+\overline{pq}=(rs+\overline{rq+sp+pq})$.

My question is what happens to the $\overline{pq}$ in the multiplication given by the book? Since multiplying two fractions doesn't necessarily give an integer, I'm not sure why $pq$ would be in $\mathbb{Z}$ and so would vanish in the quotient. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment above, the tensor algebra is graded:
$$T(M)=T_0M\oplus T_1M\oplus T_2M\oplus\cdots$$
with $T_nM=M\otimes_RM\otimes_R\cdots\otimes_RM$ ($n$ copies of $M$). The multiplication goes
$$T_nM\otimes_RT_mM\longrightarrow T_{n+m}M$$
and is given by concatenation, and distribution over the direct sum. In your case, when you write
$$(r,\bar{p})\in T(M)$$
you mean the element $r+\bar{p}$ with $r\in R=T_0M$ and $\bar{p}\in M=T_1M$. Notice that then
$$r\cdot s = r\otimes_Rs=rs\in\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}$$
and
$$r\cdot\bar{q} = r\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\bar{q}=\overline{rq}\in\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},$$
similarly for $\bar{p}\cdot s$, and
$$\bar{p}\cdot\bar{q}=0$$
as it lives in $T_2M=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you aright, $\overline{pq}$ should be an element of $M\otimes_R M$, which, as you point out, is zero.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding the product correctly. When we multiply, do we really have  $(r+\overline{p})(s+\overline{q})=r\otimes s+r\otimes\overline{q}+\overline{p}\otimes s+\overline{p\otimes q}$ but we identify $R\otimes  R$ with $R$ and $R\otimes M$ with $M$?

Comment: The tensor algebra is graded, and is $T_0\oplus T_1\oplus T_2\oplus\cdots$ where $T_0=R$, $T_1=M$, $T_2=M\otimes M$ etc.